# Crystal Reports: Hierarchical fields

Tags: crystal-reports, hierarchy

There is a table in my DB about the Departments of an Organization. This table has the Department_ID and the BasisDepartment_ID which is the ID of the "above"department. There is also another table with the above IDs and a field called Level that supposedly shows the level of the department with 0 being the bottom department and 4 the TOP. However for a level 3 I get all of the departments with level 0 to 3 when I do a SELECT statement.
This is a bit of info to understand the DB.
My problem is that I don't know how to implement the hierarchy in CR. I have been asked to make a report with 4 columns that describes the hierarchy of the departments an employee belongs to. Keep in mind that not all employees have to have 4 departments. A person could be the head of the department without belonging to it but to the department above.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried grouping the departments?

Comment: I know about hierarchical grouping but in my case is not helping because I need 4 different columns for the departments.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

```
SELECT 0 ID, 'Parent 0' NAME, null PARENT_ID FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 ID, 'Child 0' NAME, 0 PARENT_ID FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 2  ID, 'Child 1' NAME, 0 PARENT_ID FROM dual
```

Create a report that contains `ID`, `NAME`, and `PARENT_ID`:

[image]

Add a group on `ID`; customize the group's name:

[image]

Results:

[image]

Open the Report | Hierarchical Grouping Options...; set fields:

[image]

Results:

[image]

Comment: Ok, I didn't really understand the select statement but I don't think this is what i need.
I would like a row in my report to look like this:
Firstname    Lastname   Team   Unit   Department   Ressort.
And the "Team Unit Department Ressort" information is in the same field in the DB..